# Using SQL Store procedures in MVC, whats the opposite of ExecuteScalar?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've trying to get the multiple columns/results of a SQL stored procedure displaying in a view.
At the moment, my Controller look like this

```
    public class StatusController : Controller
{
    // GET: Status

    dbEntities  db = new dbEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var tdaydate = DateTime.Now;
        var command = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "dbo.pr_stored_procedure";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@day", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = tdaydate });
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       var test = (command.ExecuteScalar());

        ViewBag.res = test;
        return View();
    }

}
```

and my view has the following line

```
@model IEnumerable<dbentity.Models.SP_Stored-ProcedureRESULTS>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rooms)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ooo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rent)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.occupied)
    </th>
          etc
    <th></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    @ViewBag.res;
        </td>
</tr>
@*@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rooms)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ooo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rent)
        </td>
etc
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.rooms}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.rooms }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.rooms })
        </td>
    </tr>
}*@
```

NB: the FOREACH loop is commented out, as it was throwing up errors, and I was debugging.

Now, this is returns the value of the first column (as it should, using the ExecuteScalar command), but what do I need to do to get all the other columns/results so I can display them in the view.

I've tried adding :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter SqlDbAdapter = new
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
System.Data.DataSet SQLDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
SqlDbAdapter.SelectCommand = SqlDbCommand;
SqlDbAdapter.Fill(SQLDataSet);
SQLDataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "PR_Foo";

if (SQLDataSet.Tables.Count != 0) {
   Result1 = int.Parse(SQLDataSet.Tables[SQLDataSet.Tables.Count - 1].Rows[0][0].ToString());
   Result2 = int.Parse(SQLDataSet.Tables[SQLDataSet.Tables.Count - 1].Rows[0][1].ToString());
etc
}
```

to my controller ( after the command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure; line) , but VS complains about the SqlDbAdapter.SelectCommand = SqlDbCommand line (specifically, SqlDBCommand... "SqlDbCommand dos not exist in the current context")

[image]

Could someone tell me how I can get store the 22 different results/columns so I can call them in the view ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ExecuteReader()` and iterating through your results?  `ExecuteScalar` is going to try to return you the first column of the first row of your results.

Paring your question down to the simplest repro may help you find the answer more quickly.